# If $Q\sim\operatorname{EXP}(1.5),$ find the probability that the roots of the equation $g(t) =0$ are real, where $g(t) = 4t^2 + 4Qt + Q + 2$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have used the discriminant to find that $Q \geq 2$ and $Q \leq -1.$ I assume that since all parameters for the exponential distribution seem to refer to $x > 0,$ that we are only looking at the $Q \geq 2$ instance. I let $F(2;1.5) = 1-e^\frac{-2}{1.5} = 0.7364.$ Since $Q \geq 2$, I then set the probability to $1- 0.7364.$ It follows that the probability of the roots being real is $0.2636.$

Am I applying and understanding the process correctly? My book is great about giving us the $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ formulas to use, but then it doesn't really show anything about this idea of probability of roots. Thank you for any confirmation that I am on the right path, or assistance to send me down a better path.

Comment: Could you confirm that it's twice the **same** realization of $Q$ ?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you mean by that? This was the only information given in the question.

Comment: It looks that $Q$ has the same value in its 2 occurences (throwing away the interpretation of your quadratic as $4t^2 + 4Q_1t + Q_2 + 2$ with $Q_1 \neq Q_2$ in general).

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.